# NPE being generated when closing AlertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have an alert box popping up when my activity starts. It displays a custom view which consists of 2 textbox and 2 edittext views. For some reason when I click confirm to close the dialog and create a new object with the values entered into these fields I get an NPE. I am unsure as to why. Below is the method where I create the dialog box:

```
    public Dialog createDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    final EditText tableNum = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.numberEntry);
    final EditText coverNum = (EditText)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.coversEntry);

    builder.setMessage("Order Information");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //Create order object in here
            table = Integer.parseInt(tableNum.getText().toString());
            covers = Integer.parseInt(coverNum.getText().toString());
            order = new Order(covers,table);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "order created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "order: " + "table: " + order.getTable() + " covers: " + order.getCovers(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

This is the error I get.
ERROR:

**java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.waitron5.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)**

LOG CAT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at com.example.waitron5.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-21 16:46:31.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11983):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my order_dialog.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <!-- Table Number -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tablelabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Table Number: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:width="40dp" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <!-- Covers -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coverslabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Covers: " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/coversEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:width="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error is occuring on this line 89:

```
table = Integer.parseInt(tableNum.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `MainActivity.this.findViewById` with `v.findViewById` and it should work well

Comment: thanks that worked... I can't believe I did not see that!! Will accept answer in 10mins when I am able to